# Laravel array to update multiple rows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've done a ton of looking through older posts and no luck yet, 
I'm trying to update multiple rows within a table from a single form with the ID being the primary key.

The contents are being displayed in what looks like a spreadsheet where the user can edit multiple rows.

I'm getting an undefined index: ID error.

The code I'm using bellow seems really close though something isn't right.

If anyones done this before and can correct this code your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

```
protected function updateMultiple(Request $request)

{

    $data = $request->except(['_token']);

    //  dd($data);
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($data['id']); $i++) {

        $input = [
            'id' => $data['id'][$i],
            'Channel' => $data['Channel'][$i],
            'Posts' => $data['Posts'][$i],
            'Monthly_Admin_Fee' => $data['Monthly_Admin_Fee'][$i],
            'Legal_Fee' => $data['Legal_Fee'][$i],
            'Valuation_Fee' => $data['Valuation_Fee'][$i],
            'Mortgage_Risk_Fee' => $data['Mortgage_Risk_Fee'][$i],
        ];

        DB::table('membership')->update($input);

    }

}
```

View

```
        @foreach($members as $member)
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <input type="text" style="padding-right: 8px;padding-left: 8px;" name="id[]" id="id">{{$member->id}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Channel" name="Channel[]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Channel}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Posts" name="Posts[]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Posts}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Monthly_Admin_Fee" name="Monthly_Admin_Fee[]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Monthly_Admin_Fee}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Legal_Fee" name="Legal_Fee[]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Legal_Fee}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Valuation_Fee" name="Valuation_Fee[]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Valuation_Fee}}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Mortgage_Risk_Fee" name="Mortgage_Risk_Fee[]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Mortgage_Risk_Fee}}"></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: can you show your `$data` after this line `$data = $request->except(['_token']);`

Comment: ``array:8 [▼
  "id" => array:10 [▶]
  "Channel" => array:10 [▶]
  "Posts" => array:10 [▶]
  "Monthly_Admin_Fee" => array:10 [▶]
  "Legal_Fee" => array:10 [▶]
  "Valuation_Fee" => array:10 [▶]
  "Rate" => array:10 [▶]
  "Mortgage_Risk_Fee" => array:10 [▶]
]``

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job

view

```
@foreach($members as $member)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-right">
            <input type="text" style="padding-right: 8px;padding-left: 8px;" name="id[{{$member->id}}]" id="id">{{$member->id}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Channel" name="Channel[{{$member->id}}]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Channel}}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Posts" name="Posts[{{$member->id}}]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Posts}}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Monthly_Admin_Fee" name="Monthly_Admin_Fee[{{$member->id}}]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Monthly_Admin_Fee}}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Legal_Fee" name="Legal_Fee[{{$member->id}}]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Legal_Fee}}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Valuation_Fee" name="Valuation_Fee[{{$member->id}}]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Valuation_Fee}}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Mortgage_Risk_Fee" name="Mortgage_Risk_Fee[{{$member->id}}]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Mortgage_Risk_Fee}}"></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

controller

```
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $data ) {

            $input = [
                'id' => $data['id'][$key],
                'Channel' => $data['Channel'][$key],
                'Posts' => $data['Posts'][$key],
                'Monthly_Admin_Fee' => $data['Monthly_Admin_Fee'][$key],
                'Legal_Fee' => $data['Legal_Fee'][$key],
                'Valuation_Fee' => $data['Valuation_Fee'][$key],
                'Mortgage_Risk_Fee' => $data['Mortgage_Risk_Fee'][$key],

            ];
            DB::table('membership')->where('id',$key)->update($input);

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Divyank. This looks like it should work!

I'm still getting an undefined index error though for whats inside of the $input array. I believe it could be because it's an array inside of an array/nested array? :S

Answer (score 1):

that's  your problem

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($data['id']); $i++) {`
```

`$data` it's array of arrays, it doesn't  have element with key `'id'`

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($data); $i++) {
```

or even better

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $desired_keys = [
        'Channel',
        'Posts',
        'Monthly_Admin_Fee',
        'Legal_Fee',
        'Valuation_Fee',
        'Mortgage_Risk_Fee',
    ];
    $input = array_only($row, $desired_keys);
    BD::table('membership')->where('id', $row['id'])->update($input)
}
```

---

EDIT

Sorry, I've missled you. Because of your approach.
Can I suggest you this one?

```
@foreach($members as $i => $member)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-right">
            <input type="text" style="padding-right: 8px;padding-left: 8px;" name="members[{{ $i }}][id]" id="id">{{$member->id}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Channel" name="members[{{ $i }}][Channel]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Channel}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Posts" name="members[{{ $i }}][Posts]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Posts}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Monthly_Admin_Fee" name="members[{{ $i }}][Monthly_Admin_Fee]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Monthly_Admin_Fee}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Legal_Fee" name="members[{{ $i }}][Legal_Fee]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Legal_Fee}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Valuation_Fee" name="members[{{ $i }}][Valuation_Fee]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Valuation_Fee}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Mortgage_Risk_Fee" name="members[{{ $i }}][Mortgage_Risk_Fee]" class="form-control" value="{{$member->Mortgage_Risk_Fee}}">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Then in controller

```
protected function updateMultiple(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->get('members', []) as $member) {
        DB::table('membership')->where('id', $member['id'])
            ->update(array_except($member, ['id']))
    }
}
```

This approach is much more pretty, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you.
I've just tried with the foreach loop in your last example and I'm still getting a ``undefined index:id ``

on line ``where('id', $row['id])``
When I dd($data) I can see the ID inside of the array which appears like this

``array:8 [▼
  "id" => array:10 [▼
    0 => ""
    1 => ""
    2 => ""
    3 => ""
    4 => ""
    5 => ""
    6 => ""
    7 => ""
    8 => ""
    9 => "" ``

Comment: Thank you huuuk! that makes sense now from going through it. 
legend :)

Comment: Sorry just have one more question huuuk, 

I really like what you have said, just  the first line in the controller function is causing errors, I've added the image in my OP to better explain.

Comment: Parse error on line ``for($request->get('members', []) as $member)`` 
$member is undefined, and I'm hesitant about defining $member before the loop and reassigning it. 

I've added the image of the line in the post now.

Comment: Sorry for typo, chage `for` to `foreach`

Comment: Thank you! ugh I should have spotted that before >.<
I really appreciate your help with this huuuk, thank you so much :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again. one very last thing.

``->where('id', $member['id'])`` gives undefined index id still, I've got your code exactly the same in the view. i quickly tested with ``->where('id', '>=', 1) and it of course saved the data to every row. 

 could ``$member['id']`` potentially be something slightly different? :S

Comment: You've missed `value` attr `<input type="text" style="padding-right: 8px;padding-left: 8px;" name="members[{{ $i }}][id]" id="id" value="{{$member->id}}">`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update multiple rows with different data with one query like the `insert()` method.

When the data is the same for all rows that need to be updated, you can use:

`DB::table('membership')
    ->whereIn('id', [1,2,3,4])
    ->update(['Channel' => 'your-value', ..]);`

Else you will need to use a `foreach`, if this takes to long take a look at Queing (https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues)

Answer (score 0):

Basically without knowing your data i would say remove `[ID]`.

You dont need to know the ID. remove it from everywhere in this function,

EDIT

Just change your query to:
DB::table('membership')where(id, $data['id'][$i] )->update($input);

this will fetch the record with the current id and update it.

Comment: I think in this case the 
  ``DB::table('membership')->where('id', $row['id'])->update($input)``
Is pretty important because If I edit a row with the id of 12 and another with the id of 9. 

It would need to update both of those rows?

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in view. You have forgot to insert value to ID input.

```
<input type="text" style="padding-right: 8px;padding-left: 8px;" name="id[]" id="id" value="{{$member->id}}">{{$member->id}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow like example :

```
$data_upate = array(
  array(
    'field1'=>'value1',
    'field2'=>'value2',
    ...
  ),
  array(
    'field1'=>'value1',
    'field2'=>'value2',
    ...
  ),
);
```

// list id of record you want to update//

$a_ids = array(....);

DB::table('table_name')->whereIn('id',$a_ids)->update($data_update);